# Why the Linux command does not match the synopsis?

Tags: linux

> Ubuntu 20.10 shell

Here is the result of command `man ls`:

```
SYNOPSIS
   ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

Based on the syntax of SYNOPSIS,the `ls` command should be:

```
ls -a file1
ls -l -a file2
ls -lah file3
```

Example:

- use `ls -lah verilator`
  [ls -lah verilator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABJcC.png)
- use `ls verilator -lah`
  [ls verilator -lah](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdf2j.png)

I get the same result!

So, Why we can use `ls file1 -lah` to show the list of file1 directory? This is grammatically incorrect.

Other commands have the same problem, it is puzzling.

Comment: Its simply how command line arguments are parsed for the [gnu coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). It doesn't matter where the `OPTIONS` are placed they are treated as `OPTIONS` rather than a file pattern. The usage text is not clear about this so it makes sense that you'd be confused.

Comment: There is nothing wrong about accepting a command line structure not (explicitly) described in a `man` page — which specifies what the command *does* accept, not what it *must not* accept. In theory, it would be prudent to assume that arguments *not* matching a documented synopsis yield undefined behavior. In practice, please just read `man 3 getopt` before judging what is “grammatically incorrect”: *“By  default,  `getopt()`  permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.”* There. This is why `ls` behaves the way it does.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have understood what you mean.